# Finding minimum value of a square root function

Tags: calculus

Given that x is a real number, find the minimum value of $\sqrt{(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+1}$

Attempt:

Let z= (x + 2018)

$\sqrt{(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)+1}$

First derivative of the equation gives me a value of $z = -1/2$, giving a miniumum of 5/4?

But i tried plugging -2017 to the equation, giving a value of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set it equal to $0$ and find the zeros, since it is a square root function, the values cannot be $<0$ in this case.

Here, you know it *must* have a real zero, since there is nothing in the function located "outside" the square root.

$\sqrt{(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+1}=0$

$(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+1=0$

Let $a=x+2017$

$a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)+1=0$

$a^4+6a^3+11a^2+6a+1=0$

$(a^2 + 3a + 1)^2=0$

$a= \cfrac 32 \pm \cfrac{\sqrt5}{2}$

Since $a=x+2017$

$x+2017=\cfrac 32 \pm \cfrac{\sqrt5}{2}$

Comment: Are there no instances when it can't be equal to 0?

Comment: @Janjan Yes, in that case the roots are imaginary, and you'll have to find the absolute minimum/maximum from the derivative: $f'(x)$

Comment: "Here, you KNOW it MUST have a real zero, since there is nothing in the function located "outside" the square root."  I don't understand what that means.  a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3) is only negative if -3 < a < 2 or -1< a < 0 and there is near immediately apparent reason it will ever have a value as low as -1.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what your are saying.

Comment: @fleablood $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has $x$-intercept at $x=0$, yet there is no real $x$-intercept with the function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}+1$.

Comment: That is what I mean by "outside" the square root.

Comment: Yes but $f(x) = \sqrt {g(x)}$ has an $x$ intercept of $g(x) = 0$.  So this will have a real zero if $g(x) = (x + 2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+ 1 = 0$.  But we don't have any reason to say that $g(x)$ will have a zero value.  It does, but it wasn't apparant at the time you said we KNOW it MUST.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing is
$$ t(t+1)(t+2)(t+3) + 1 = \left( t^2 + 3 t + 1 \right)^2  $$
Let's see, we have
$$  \left| t^2 + 3 t + 1 \right| $$
which does achieve zero when $$ t = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} $$

[image]

Comment: Then i plug x+2017 back to the equation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to quibble that it asked what the minimum can be; not at which $x$ value it is achieved.

$\sqrt{(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+1} \ge 0$ so the absolute minimum possible is $0$, if $(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020) = -1$.

Let $a = x + 2018.5$ then $$(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)= (a - \frac 32)(a-\frac 12)(a+\frac 12)(a+\frac 32) = (a^2 -\frac 94)(a^2 -\frac 14)=a^4 - \frac {10}4a^2 +\frac 9{16} = 1$$ if

$$a^2 = \frac {\frac {5}2 \pm \sqrt {\frac {25}4 - \frac9{4}}}{2} = \frac 54 \pm 2=\frac {13}4$$

So $\sqrt{(x+2017)(x+2018)(x+2019)(x+2020)+1} = 0$ if $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}2 + 2018.5$